# Q: Rstudio (latest) broken on Windows 8 x64 (object RMD5 not found)?

Tags: r, rstudio

This the the error I get when I try to install or update any packages within Rstudio (latest version) on Windows 8 x64:

"Error in install.packages : object 'Rmd5' not found."

Answer (score 0):

Try running the install or update in straight old R 64 bit version.

If you can make that fly. I would install installR using R 64 bit (NOT STUDIO) you can then use that to update any and all packages and versions of R pretty effortlessly. It manages dependencies and errors well.

Comment: I would try updating your installation of R itself and then RStudio to see if  there is a problem with the environment.